# Best procedure to renew a driveway

Tags: sealing, driveway, patch, asphalt

My asphalt driveway has a lot of narrow cracks, and it has some shallow depressions where puddles form.

I've watched some youtube videos.  All agree that before starting, oil spills should be cleaned with detergent, and cracks should have the sediment removed with a power washer.

Some videos suggest that the depressions can be leveled with patching material, but some suggest two or more layers of a thick gravel-less liquid.

For the cracks, some videos show a crack-filling product that you have to pour along each and every crack.  Others show a product that gets poured on an area and then gets worked into the cracks with a brush (kind of like a push broom but with less bristles).  It seems like the latter would be easier, given the large number of cracks in this driveway.

After these two steps, then there is the sealing.  I didn't find consensus on how long to wait after filling the cracks and the depressions before sealing.

My goal is to have a nice-looking driveway for at least two years.  I don't require it to look good for ten or twenty years.  Also note that it's a small driveway which fits two cars (parked in a line).

What is the best procedure and sequence for a DIY project?  Would I fill the cracks first, or level the depressions first?  I'm clear about temperature conditions, powerwashing, allowing to dry, and the instructions for curing (spray gently with water every day for the first few days).

Comment: Depends on the products used.

Comment: @JeffCates - I don't know if you're allowed to make suggestions -- but suggestions would be welcome.  I would prefer not to have to dribble something into every little crack.  If I could brush or squeegee something over all the cracks that would be preferable.

Comment: The problem with brushing something, is the thickness of the repair. It will crack and break. Also, if you live in a cold climate, snow/ice, and you use or the city/county/state use salt or de-icers, they eat concrete. There are driveway patch systems that are sold at home improvement stores. What you might be looking for is an epoxy type patch/sealer or a concrete resurfacer. I have done small repairs to my walkway, but they only seem to last about a year because they are shallow repairs, and snow/ice and de-icer eat away at it.

Comment: @JeffCates - Thanks.  But wait -- are you talking about concrete?  I'm talking about asphalt.

Comment: In that case, look for asphalt patcher. You can use asphalt patch on concrete as well, just not aesthetically pleasing.